# How to stream videos from my One Drive Business in Windows Store app using Office 365 Api?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-office, office365

I want to know about that how can we stream videos from one my one drive using Office 365 api, Is it possible or we have to download file first

I am exploring the following api provided by Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-file-tasks-client-library#GetClient

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

No you can't stream it using the O365 REST API, you'll have to download the file first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try HTTP progressive download mechanism that doesn't require full file to be downloaded prior to playback. The media player has to be capable of playing with buffered data. On most modern players that is supported.